# Why mails sent internally, disappear upon arrival?

Tags: email-server, windows-server-2016, outlook, outlook-web-app, exchange-2016

I have a problem with internal mail flow. On one shared mailbox I have this issue, that when email is sent to it, some users don't get it. It's Microsoft Exchange Server 2016.

I did use Test-Mailflow and was logged in over OWA, to confirm this case.

What I have seen is that I have successful Test-Mailflow Result, and mail do arrive at it's destination, but disappear after a second.

Why is this happening I was not able to understand, but what I did found out is when I restart Microsoft Exchange Information Store service, it starts working fine.

But after a day or so, this problem happens again.

Does anyone had similar problem so far?

**Update #1**

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Ww5YVLz3) is MessageTrackingLog.
You can see it here log for one particular internal mail which is problematic.
****note***
One user which was not reached, is no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Check your filters and rules. A filter/rule could be moving the emails to an obsolete folder and thus removing them.

Comment: On this mailbox, there is one rule but not related to this. Rule is to delete email from one specific email address (this address though is from internal space)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**message tracking logs**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/search-message-tracking-logs?view=exchserver-2016#use-the-exchange-management-shell-to-search-the-message-tracking-logs) to see if there is any **[event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/message-tracking?view=exchserver-2016#event-types-in-the-message-tracking-log)**(e.g. **FAIL**) and **[source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/message-tracking?view=exchserver-2016#source-values-in-the-message-tracking-log)**(e.g. **MAILBOXRULE**) affecting the message delivery of the problematic mailboxes:

> **Why is this happening I was not able to understand, but what I did found out is when I restart Microsoft Exchange Information Store service, it starts working fine.**

Based on the official documentation **[Exchange services on Mailbox servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/deployment-ref/services-overview?view=exchserver-2016)**, this service is used to manage the mailbox databases on the server. If this service is stopped, mailbox databases on the server are unavailable. Please try to run the following command to see if these problematic problems are locating in the same database:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | ft Name, Database -AutoSize
```

Comment: There is no FAIL or MAILBOXRULE
HAREDIRECTFAIL
RECEIVE
REDIRECT
AGENTINFO
RESUBMIT
AGENTINFO
TRANSFER
SEND

Those are Events.

Regarding mailbox, this mailbox uses correct Mailbox Database.

Comment: You could provide the output result of the message tracking log in your reply, it should be helpful for us to troubleshoot(Please replace your personal info, such as email address with a false one).

Comment: Posted in Update #1

Comment: What's the sender and recipient of the missing emails? Sender(**Sophie.Armstrong@contoso.com**), recipient(**Lacey.Davis@contoso.com**)? Based on the message tracking log, the test email wasn't sent to **Lacey.Davis@contoso.com** because of the non-existing email address(***'[{LED=550 5.1.10 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipientNotFound; Recipient not found by SMTP address lookup};{MSG=};{FQDN=};{IP=};{LRT=}]'***).

Comment: Exactly, sender is Sophie.Armstrong@contoso.com. 
Like mentioned in Update #1, Lacey.Davis@contoso.com is deleted user, by intention, and this is not important.

Comment: Please try sending a test email from the sender(**Sophie**) to the mailbox that the email missed in its inbox folder again, and run the following command to do a message trace(Please keep the field entries, such as **Recipients**, **Sender**): **Get-MessageTrackingLog -Sender Sophie.Armstrong@contoso.com -Recipients <Recipient Email Address> -MessageSubject "<Subject>" | ft SourceContext, EventId, Source, Recipients, Sender**.

Comment: Based on the log you attached above, because it's a little messy, I could only found that the emails were ever redirected(**REDIRECT**: *A message was redirected to an alternative recipient after an Active Directory lookup.*) to some alternative recipients(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/mail-routing/recipient-resolution?view=exchserver-2019#expansion), please check if there is any outlook/transport rule/email forward(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/user-mailboxes/email-forwarding?view=exchserver-2019) configured for the recipient to redirect emails.

Comment: There is one redirect, but for this it is set up to forward mail to specific address, with option to deliver to both forwarding address and mailbox, enabled.
Will check now with this test email you suggested.

Comment: Ok, I only need it in a state when is failing, as currently all works fine, I'm not able to notice anything suspicious.

Comment: If there is any same issue after that, you're welcome to post it :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, for help!