# Email disappearance on Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

I have an issue with the disappearance of emails, from the particular mailbox. I have one mailbox  and it has a security group on it.

Emails disappear when it is being sent from internal users usually. Not really sure if it happened with external users.

In the security group, only 2 members have the possibility to delete the emails and those 2 members are actually directly connected to the mailbox.

In transaction logs I do see that email is being sent to this mailbox and one user claimed that they saw the actual email come and disappear immediately.

In deleted emails there is nothing and nothing can be recovered. This is also empty.
I guess if it was deleted by the user, it should be available for recovery, as retention is set to 30 days.

Exchange is version 15.1 ‎(Build 2308.8)‎ - but it happened on prior versions.
Here is the prior post to this issue:
[Why mails sent internally, disappear upon arrival?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1042913/why-mails-sent-internally-disappear-upon-arrival)

Any advice on what I'm looking for?

Comment: **I have one mailbox and it has a security group on it.** - What do you mean by that? Do you mean that a security group has delegated access to the mailbox? Have you checked for any rules that might be deleting the email?

Comment: Correct, Security group have delegated access to the mailbox. 
Yes, checked on rules, but there is nothing I saw that have anything related which can trigger such mail deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Does the mailbox give the full access permission to another mailbox?
If in this case, please check if emails in the other mailbox’s junk folder.
You can also use mailbox audit logging.
https://practical365.com/tracking-mailbox-owner-deletes-using-mailbox-audit-logging/

Comment: Is there any hidden rule in outlook client? Run below command to check it.                         Get-InboxRule -Mailbox user@contoso.com.    Here's a similar thread for you. https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2180030-hidden-rules

Comment: Hi, is there any update?